# Itext : Add New line when element is added to new Page

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

i am adding an element to itext pdf using code:

```
((com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable) element).setKeepTogether(true);
document.add(element);
```

One of the element text is of 2 pages and hence it is added to second page. But on second page I want to leave first 2 lines blank for adding header. 
**Any suggestion how can i leave 2 lines blank of the new page?**

Comment: You should leave area empty for headers by setting the margins accordingly.

Comment: @mkl that is what i am asking how?, i did try  ** document.top(1000); ** , no difference found.

Comment: Use `document.setMargins(left, right, top, bottom)` and do so before the page in question is generated. And 1000 is too large, an A4 page has a height of only 842 units...

Comment: @mkl that 1000 is just an dummy number, cant show actual code or values so. error is well solved and rather than setting values in mothod setMargins, I used its constructor to pass value, While creating object. Thanks allot for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I have found my answer instead of using `Document document = new Document();` , I used [Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER,30,30,60,35)](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-does-my-header-overlap-my-content)

Answer (score 1):

Try add Paragraph:

```
document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
```

Comment: Eugen, As you see,  "document.add(element);" adds the whole element directly, As the element contains two pages text, It will directly added to 2 pages. I know about  "document.add(new Paragraph("\n")); and document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE); " , ** In this particular, I dont understand how to add new line, into a single element. **

Answer (score 0):

```
String S = "Your text here" + "\n" + "Hello"; //  *\n is to go for next line*
PdfPCell insideTableCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(S));
*//this is using itextpdf, you can get a jar file or maven import*
```